# Android Java - use methods from other activityClass

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I am pretty new in android java development. I try to implement a QR-Code-Scanner. I found a nice class which implements this functions. But I want to seperate this class.

I have two classes.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public class QrCodeScanner extends Activity
```

From the `MainActivity` I want to call the method

```
public void scanQR(View v)
```

How can this work?

I can't create a Instance from `QrCodeScanner` Class.

Thanks in advance!

```
public class QrCodeScanner extends Activity {

static final String ACTION_SCAN = "com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //set the main content layout of the Activity
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

//product qr code mode
public void scanQR(View v) {
    try {
        //start the scanning activity from the com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN intent
        Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_SCAN);
        intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
        //on catch, show the download dialog
        showDialog(QrCodeScanner.this, "No Scanner Found", "Download a scanner code activity?", "Yes", "No").show();
    }
}

//alert dialog for downloadDialog
private static AlertDialog showDialog(final Activity act, CharSequence title, CharSequence message, CharSequence buttonYes, CharSequence buttonNo) {
    AlertDialog.Builder downloadDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(act);
    downloadDialog.setTitle(title);
    downloadDialog.setMessage(message);
    downloadDialog.setPositiveButton(buttonYes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://search?q=pname:" + "com.google.zxing.client.android");
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            try {
                act.startActivity(intent);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {

            }
        }
    });
    downloadDialog.setNegativeButton(buttonNo, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
        }
    });
    return downloadDialog.show();
}

//on ActivityResult method
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == 0) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            //get the extras that are returned from the intent
            String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
            String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Have both classes inherit from a base class that extends `AppCompatActivity` containing the relevant method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method is only actually starting an intent for another activity, so why don't you create this method in another class, so you'll be able to invoke it from anywhere with context paramaeter:

```
 //product qr code mode
public void scanQR(View v, Context ctx) {
    try {
        //start the scanning activity from the com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN intent
        Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_SCAN);
        intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
        ((Activity) ctx).startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
        //on catch, show the download dialog
    }
}
```

The result of the scan should be delivered to the activity holding the context.

Comment: Many thanks for the quick response. You mean, with your solution, it's not required to inherit from Activity? What is with the method "onActivityResult"?

Comment: Ahh i got it :) Thanks again.